Can't read my user files from internal hard drive using USB 3.0 To SATA and IDE Cable
I am using a USB 3.0 to SATA adaptor to recover data from some old internal hard drives from old laptops. The hard drive had been used on a Windows 11 laptop.
I can see all of the folder structures including the user folder and the folders for each of my users but the user folders are empty.
It has been this way on both hard drives I have looked at.
Is there something I need to do in order to see the user files?

Please [edit] the question to include the operating system and the file system on the drive.

Did you take ownership of the Users folders?  How certain are you the files should be there? Missing files suggest the HDD was retired for a reason.

Ramhound's comment was correct. It was an ownership issue.
I followed the directions from Access User Folder Old Hard Drive to update the ownership. I also used Fix Enumerate Objects Error when I got tired of clicking continue.
Once I got the ownership issue fixed I could see my files.
